# Animate with position fixed without "shooting up"

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to animate this box to go full screen, but because I'm setting the position to fixed before the animation starts, the box will shoot up to the upper left corner.

**Instead, is there a way to make it expand from its starting position?**

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.test').css({
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    margin: 0
  });
    
  $('.test').animate({
    height: $(window).height(),
    width: $(window).width()
  }, 200);
}, 2000);
```

```css
.test {
    margin: 0 50px;
    background: blue;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Instead of animating the height and width what happens if you animation top left right and bottom to 0px instead?

Comment: Nope, will still shoot up due to the fixed I think: http://jsfiddle.net/yqxzq65h/

Answer (score 1):

I would mix up a bit of CSS and JS. Try this: **[DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ybrhatu5/7/)**

JS:

```
$('.test').css({
    'top': $('.test').position().top,
});

setTimeout(function () {
    $('.test').addClass("full_screen");
}, 2000);


setTimeout(function () {
    $('.test').removeClass("full_screen");
}, 8000);
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}
.test {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 50px;
    background: #ccc;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    transition: all 4s;
}
.full_screen {
    top: 0px !important;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it looks like this one still shoots up to the top before the animation starts.

Comment: With this example if you add in the top to the .test css of 50px, it will animate up. The problem with that is you will need to know the element top position and set it first.

Comment: I tried setting `$('.test').css("top", $('.test').offset.top);` in the JS but I guess that won't matter since it gets overwritten by `.full_screen`. If you mean setting a static height in the CSS, I'm afraid that won't be possible as the height will change depending on the content.

Comment: `$('.test').css("transition", 'none'); setTimeout(function() {$('.test').addClass('full_screen').css("top", $('.test').offset.top+'px'); setTimeout(function() { $('.test').css("transition", 'all 1s'); setTimeout(function() { $('.test').css("top", 0px');},10); },10);},10);` I found i have to put a delay in to get it to work right which is why the set Timeouts are there. BUT you remove the transition, set the top, add the transition, then set the top again.

Comment: ok I see what you mean. I updated my fiddle using some of your techniques. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I did. check out the latest. You might need to refresh this page.

Comment: BAM! Looks Great! @CodeGodie

Comment: Great work guys - but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work if there's a scrollbar involved: https://jsfiddle.net/ybrhatu5/6/

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. Try it out, and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I like your changes, but it doesn't seem to like it if you add more paragraphs before and after the box: https://jsfiddle.net/ybrhatu5/8/

Comment: Unfortunately no, if you scroll a bit before it expands it won't really work. But I think what I should be doing here is just using a popup / modal window instead.. HUGE HUGE thanks for helping me out though..

Comment: No problem. Sorry I couldn't find the exact answer you were looking for.